# How to convert Solr query response to json using solrpy library?

Tags: json, solr

Basically, I'm trying to convert the query response from Solr server into a json object that can be passed to a third party api. However, as per my code below, I'm not able to do it:

```
    import solr
    import json

    if __name__=='__main__':
    s = solr.SolrConnection('http://localhost:8983/solr')
    op = open('output.json','w')

    for term in ['searchstring1','searchstring2','searcstring']:
        t = s.query('title:%s'%term,rows=100, wt='json')
        for news in t.results:
            op.write(news)
```

Output: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "querying.py", line 11, in 
    op.write(news)
TypeError: expected a character buffer object

I have very briefly read about Solr and just found this solrpy library to store the query result in a json format. Any help in this regard will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to write the actual python dictionary to the file, and not a json representation of it. The error message is trying to tell you that the object you're passing in can not be used as a character buffer directly. Try to use `json.dumps` to create a JSON representation as a string before writing it to a file.